# focus({preventScroll: true}) not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I can't seem to get `element.focus({preventScroll:true});` to work in Chrome although it's working perfectly in IE11.  Has anyone else experienced this?  Using this in Chrome results in the element not becoming focused at all.

Comment: Have you tried `preventScroll:true` as seen in [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus#Focus_prevent_scroll)?

Comment: @showdev yes, sorry my code is actually `element.focus({preventScroll:true});`  -- I'll update my question. Thanks!

Comment: Can we see your complete code? I'll give it a try in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to due with [focus issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484276/focus-not-working-in-chrome) in chrome

[another link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523597/javascript-focus-on-div-element-not-working-on-chrome)

If you run the focus code for buttons from the example in the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus#Focus_prevent_scroll) in Chrome vs Firefox, you'll see the difference.

you can try:

```
window.setTimeout(function ()
{
  document.getElementById('element').focus({preventScroll:true});
}, 0);
```

However without more code its hard to debug a solution for you.